# Modeling Workflow in C# Application

Tags: c#, workflow

I am planning on making a change to the data layer of my application and would like to determine every method which depends on the method I am changing. Is there an easier way to find all these relationships other than clicking on the method and selecting "Find Usages", then performing the same step on each method returned until I get to the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper 5 comes out soon, and amongst many other useful features, has a feature called "Call tracking" that does **exactly** what you are describing.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/whatsnew_50.html#code_analysis

Comment: I tried both ndepend and resharper 5 ERC and resharper was closer to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you get NDepend, you can find all direct and indirect things that a method/class/etc uses or is used by.